# How to proxy requests from Nginx to SSL server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tls

My `curl` request looks as follows:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic BASE_64" https://example.com --tlsv1 -k
```

(I need to explicitly provide `TLS` and skip verification)

and it works. I'd like to setup `nginx` to act as middleware and handle authentication for remote server.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass                         {{ remote_server }};
  proxy_set_header Host              $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header Authorization     "Basic {{ base64_token }}";
}
```

Unfortunately with these settings I got 403 forbidden. What I'm doing different than in `curl` request?

---

My `error.log` shows:

```
2014/12/20 02:40:12 [error] 15676#0: *13 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: MY_OWN_IP, server: _, request: "GET /MY_REQUESTED_ENDPOINT HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://MY_REMOTE_UPSTREAM", host: "MY_SERVER_IP"
2014/12/20 02:40:24 [info] 15676#0: *15 client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while waiting for request, client: MY_OWN_IP, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

---

The very important thing is that `MY_UPSTREAM` accepts connections only from `MY_SERVER_UP`, that's why I'm creating this middleware.

Comment: What are the contents of your error log for the requests made which fail?

Comment: Actually there's no fail messages in error log.

Comment: Given that you're seeing an access denied message, you should at least see that mirrored in the log - it might be a good idea to increase the logging verbosity while you troubleshoot, to debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final working configuration is

```
location / {
  proxy_pass                         {{ remote_server }};
  proxy_set_header Authorization     "Basic {{ base64_token }}";
}
```

We shouldn't pass neither `$host` (we want our middleware to be host) nor `$scheme` (I don't use SSL on the middleware, while upstream uses).